# How to export message history in Miranda IM?

Tags: miranda-im

Is there any way I can export my message history in [Miranda IM](http://www.miranda-im.org/) in any form? For example to a simple text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution – message export plugin.
Fresh version of it is on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msg-export/).